# mass delete names from opp

Tags: opportunity, delete, bulk-delete, remove

I have a custom field on an opportunity record called **Team Member**.

If **Team Member** contains one of the names below, then I must delete the name.

Is dataloader the best way to do this? or is there standard salesforce functionality built in that would work?

- Joe Bloggs
- John Smith
- Oliver Twist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, If you already export the Opportunity details (which contains the mentioned name in Team Member field) in `.csv` file format means, You can able to empty the mentioned field by using `data loader`.

OR

You can use this update via developer console by executing following apex code,

```
List<Opportunity> updateList = new List<Opportunity>();
List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
oppList = [SELECT Id, Name, Team_Member__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Team_Member__c IN ('Oliver Twist', 'John Smith', 'Joe Bloggs')];
for (Opportunity Opp : oppList) {
   Opp.Team_Member__c = '';
    updateList.add(Opp);
}
Update updateList;
```